# columns duplicate when setColumn is called

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

### I want to create a function that updates the columns when it is activated

I’m  using react hooks  and react beautiful DnD when I try using the splice method on one of the items inside  the column the setColumns return A duplicate column and does not update the current column,

Im trying to find a solution but I need help

this is the file

```js
const [orders, setOrders] = useState([]);
      

    useEffect(() => {
        props.fetchOrder(setOrders)
        
    },[])

    const columnsFromBackend = {
        newOrder: {
            name: "Requested",
          items: [],
          },
        inProgres: {
            name: "In Progres",
            items: [],
          },
        finished: {
            name: "Finished",
            items: [],
          },
        deliverd: {
            name: "Deliverd",
            items: [],
          },
    } 
    
const [columns, setColumns] = useState(columnsFromBackend)
console.log(columns);

    useEffect(() => {
        setColumns(prevState => {
            return {
                ...prevState,
                newOrder: {
                    ...prevState.newOrder,
                    items: orders
                }
            };
        });
    }, [orders]);
   
   const onDragEnd  = (result , columns, setColumns) => {
        if(!result.destination) return;
        const {source, destination} = result;
        if(source.droppableId !== destination.droppableId){
        const sourceColumns = columns[source.droppableId];
        const destColumns = columns[destination.droppableId];
        const sourceItems = [...sourceColumns.items];
        const destItems = [...destColumns.items];
        const [removed] = sourceItems.splice(source.index, 1);
        destItems.splice(destination.index, 0, removed);
        setColumns({
                ...columns,
                [source.droppableId]: {
                    ...sourceColumns,
                    items: sourceItems
                },
                [destination.droppableId]: {
                    ...destColumns,
                    items:destItems
                }
            })
        } else {
        const column = columns[source.droppableId];
        const copiedItems = [...column.items]
        const [removed] = copiedItems.splice(source.index, 1);
        copiedItems.splice(destination.index, 0, removed);
            setColumns({
                ...columns,
                [source.droppableId]: {
                    ...column,
                    items: copiedItems
                }
            });}
       
        
        console.log(result)
      }
      
console.log(columns);
```

and this is the delete function I can’t ant get right

```js
const deleteItem = (item, columns, column, setColumns, index) => {
  
   const itemId = item._id
   const columnsArray = columns
   const copyColumns = [...column.items]
   console.log(columnsArray);
   copyColumns.splice(index, 1);
   
   console.log(copyColumns)
   setColumns( {
        ...columnsArray,
            [columnsArray]:{
                ...column,
               items:copyColumns
               }});
    dispatch(deleteOrder(itemId));
};
```

the console.log return

> {newOrder: {…}, inProgres: {…}, finished: {…}, deliverd: {…}, [object Object]: {…}}

the setColumns created new column [object Object]: {…}

how can I make the setColumns to insert the new data and not duplicate it?

Comment: Instead of this `[columnsArray]:{...column}` you have to use the key of the object you want to update. Ie, it should be `["newOrder" | "inProgress" | "finished" | "delivered"]: {...}`

Comment: well it kinda  works , but the problem  now is that it doesn’t take  the specific column  its just  replacing the first  column

Comment: Did you actually write `"newOrder" | "inProgress" | "finished" | "delivered"` because that will return 0 and update the first element of the array. I think you'll want to search for "js update a single element in an array" and you'll get tons of answers.